# What does this error mean from App Store Connect

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,... . Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

> ITMS-90129: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.

> Best regards,

> The App Store Team

I tried to resubmit the file 6 times. I renamed my bundle. I still keep on getting the email/error again and again. I'm also doing this from Xcode.

Comment: and how about changing display name also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the display name of the app, it's pretty common that it's already been taken. You can do so in the project settings...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of this. I changed the display name and it worked like a charm.